# Determine the name of the calling class (parent or child) in parent class method

Tags: php

Looking for a clean way to determine the class (in this case, either parent or child class) of the method that calls a method in the parent class.

I thought late static binding could handle this, but seems like that only really works for calling a static method directly, and not from within an instantiated object's method.

Consider the following:

```
abstract class ParentClass {

    public function parentMethod() {
        self::_log("parent.non.static");
    }

    public static function parentStatic() {
        self::_log("parent.static");
    }

    public static function getClassName() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }

    protected static function _log($key) {
        $prefix = 'graphite.key.prefix';
        $class  = static::getClassName(); // gets the object's class, not calling class

        $g_key = "{$prefix}.{$class}.{$key}";
        echo "{$g_key} \n";

        // Graphite::increment($g_key);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public function childMethod() {
        self::_log("child.non.static");
    }

    public static function childStatic() {
        self::_log("child.static");
    }

    public static function getClassName() {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}


$obj = new ChildClass;

$obj->childMethod();           // graphite.key.prefix.ChildClass.child.non.static
$obj->parentMethod();          // graphite.key.prefix.ChildClass.parent.non.static

ParentClass::parentStatic();   // graphite.key.prefix.ParentClass.parent.static
ChildClass::childStatic();     // graphite.key.prefix.ChildClass.child.static
```

Looking for a clean way to get the class that calls the _log() method without having to pass it in as a parameter.  Doesn't have to be static at all, but I was playing around with the late static binding, because I thought that would work, but it just gets the name of the instantiated object, not the child/parent class of the method that calls the _log() method :-/

Edit:

Just to be clear, I'm after getting the class name of the method that called _log() from within the instantiated object (like parentMethod() and childMethod())  Don't care if _log() is static or not.  If that makes it easier, fine.  But the static ParentClass::parentStatic() and ChildClass::childStatic() were just to show late static bindings and what I figured might work, but not from calling within an instantiated object

Comment: `get_class($this)` maybe?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn There's no `$this` in a static method.

Comment: @Barmar OP specifically says that it doesn't have to be static.

Comment: get_class($this) won't work because it will return the name of the object that was instantiated for $obj, which is ChildClass, and won't ever return ParentClass

Comment: Gotcha, so it isn't just child calling parent. It is child calling parent which calls another method under itself. You want parent in that case. Like `$instance->childMethod()` that calls `parent::parentMethod1()` that calls `self::parentMethod2()`. In `parentMethod2` you want to show that it was called by `parentMethod1` (or really just parent). If that is the case, the only method I know of would be to parse `debug_backtrace()`. Although, it isn't that bad considering the calling function/class would always be at key `1`.

Comment: Yea.  Basically wanted to have one logging method in the parent class, and it will be called from both the parent and child classes (from the instantiated $obj, not statically from outside the class).  Figured there would be a clean way to do it, but I'm not so sure now

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php

```
class One {
    public static function test() {
        echo get_called_class() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Two extends One {}

One::test();
Two::test();
```

Output:

```
One
Two
```

Also, according to the top comment in the docs `static::class` also works as of PHP 5.5.

Comment: that's the same as what I have.  I'm looking for getting the class name of the non static method that calls the _log() method from within the instantiated object... calling it from outside the class like that works, obv

Comment: @giantNinja so in the `_log()` method you want to get the name of the *calling* method?

Comment: @giantNinja as you say "parsing debug_backtrace is terribly inefficient and not very clean" which I agree with. My log function calls usually look like `$this->log("[%s] A thing happened with %s!", [__METHOD__, $somevar], 'crit');` which gets fed into `sprintf()` to generate the final message.

Comment: yea, mine too... I am logging some stuff in graphite, and part of the key is the class where i'm calling the `_log()` method from is what I'd like to be able to use, like if I called the `_log()` method like `$this->_log('foo.key', __CLASS__)` and used that second parameter as part of the key in `_log()`, but I'm trying to avoid having to pass that for every method call.  It's not the end of the world, but it's just something I thought could be done easily, but idk now

Comment: @giantNinja you could always just shoehorn in `function _log() { /* ... */; parent::_log(); }` to all of your classes and only have to write the extra bits once per class. :P

Comment: yea, that's kinda what I've been thinking is the best compromise... Won't have to bloat each method call, just an extra method that is basically like a proxy to the main _log() method, where all the logic will be, still not duplicated... unless someone comes up with a better solution, I'm probably gonna do some sort of flavor of that

Comment: @giantNinja You could always stuff it into a trait.

Answer (score 0):

[get_class](http://php.net) will get the class name of a class instance. This can also be called on `$this` within a class. If you have a class that extends/implements another, `$this` will refer the the instantiated class, meaning the child class.

Another option is to use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace) to get the stack of functions that lead up to where you currently are. You can parse the returned array to get whatever you need including line numbers, classes, functions, methods, whatever.

Comment: This will work for the non-static methods, but there's no `$this` in static methods.

Comment: Right, so the same thing as what's happening here.  It will get the class name of the instantiated object (ChildClass in this case), and not the class that called the method.  And parsing debug_backtrace is terribly inefficient and not very clean, so that's not what I'm after.  I'd rather just pass the class as a param at that point